# Managing high-volume writes to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I have a web service that is used to manage files on a filesystem that are also tracked in a Microsoft SQL Server database. We have a .NET system service that watches for files that are added using the FileSystemWatcher class. When a file-added callback comes from FileSystemWatcher, metadata about the file is added to our database, and it works fairly well.

I've now come to a bit of a scalability problem. I'm adding large quantities of files to the filesystem in rapid succession, and this ends up hammering the database with file adds which results in locking up my web front-end.

I have yet to work on database scability issues, so I'm trying to come up with mitigate tactics. I was thinking of perhaps caching file adds and only writing them off to the database every five minutes or so, but I'm not sure how practical that is. This is data that needs to find its way into our database at some point anyway, and so it's going to have to get hammered at some point. Maybe I could limit the number of file db entries written per second to a certain amount, but then I risk having that amount be less than the rate at which files are added. How can I best tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using something like [SQL Server Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)? That way you could push through tons of entries in a burst and it would level out the inserts into your database.

Basically you'd be pushing messages onto a queue which would then be consumed by a receiver stored procedure that would perform the insert for you. You could limit the maximum number of receivers executing to help with the responsiveness issues in your web interface.

There's a nice intro paper [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345108%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). Although it's for 2005, not much has changed between 2005 and the newer versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You have a performance problem and you should approach it with a performance investigation methodology like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). Once you identify the *actual* problem, we can discuss solutions.

*This is just a guess* but, assuming the notification 'update metadata' code is a stright forward insert, the likely problem is that you're generating one transaction per notification. This results in commit flush waits, see [Diagnosing Transaction Log Performance](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/12/09/diagnosing-transaction-log-performance-issues-and-limits-of-the-log-manager.aspx) . Batch commit (aggregate multiple notifications before committing) is the canonical solution.

Answer (score 0):

first option is using Caching to handle high-volume data. or using clusters for analysis high volume data. please [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/big-data-cluster-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information.